# Intermediate SQL Table : What for?

Tags: mysql, java-ee-7

I'm managing to create my first complicated J2E Solution and in every tutorial I find some sort of intermediary tables usage, like here :

Tables : User, User_Roles, Roles
While logic would simply add a key to user Table referring to it's role on Roles table, why the usage of that intermediary table ?

I thought it's one or two developpers choice, but everywhere I look for a tutorial, I find this sort of sql schema.

Is it better ? Does it help in something particular ? Speed, security ? Cause from a logic point of view, using one table User and a foreign key to Roles is better.

Thank you

Comment: You need it for an n-m relationship:  multiple users can have multiple roles.

Comment: No i have a school system. A teacher cant be a student

Comment: If a user can have only a single role then you don't need the table in between.

Comment: But (for instance) a Principal can be a teacher...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common database relationship  modeling called M-N (Many To Many). A User can have many Roles, and a Role can be assigned to many Users, so you need the intermediary table. Here's another example: a Teacher can teach many Classes, and each Class can be taught by many teachers (during different semesters, for example). In this case you need a Teacher-Class intermediary table.

A different kind of relationship is 1-N (one to N). A User can have many Telephones, but each Telephone is owned by a single User. In this case, a User's primary key (PK) is exported as a foreign key (FK) into the Telephones table. No need for an intermediary table.

Comment: So for my example i dont need it for user who can be a teacher or student

Comment: At first, no. You will need an Occupation table with a PK (int) and a description of the Occupation (student, professor, etc). And Occupation's PK will be exported as FK to User (but column value can be NULL).